# It is possible to render the whole content of a TScrollBox control to a image file?

Tags: delphi, controls, capture, delphi-2009

I tried this function, but it only caputre the visible client area... It is possible to capture the whole area of the control, like it is expanded that no vertical scroll bar is needed ?

```
function CaptureWinCtrlImage(AWinControl: TWinControl; AImg: TGraphic): Boolean;
var
  vBmp: Graphics.TBitmap;
  vControlDC: HDC;
begin
  Result:= False;
  if not AWinControl.HandleAllocated then Exit;
  vControlDC:= GetWindowDC(AWinControl.Handle);
  try
    vBmp:= Graphics.TBitmap.Create;
    try
      vBmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
      vBmp.Height := AWinControl.Height;
      vBmp.Width  := AWinControl.Width;
      BitBlt(vBmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, vBmp.Width, vBmp.Height, vControlDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
      AImg.Assign(vBmp);
      Result:= True;
    finally
      vBmp.Free;
    end;
  finally
    ReleaseDC(AWinControl.Handle, vControlDC);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That function always returns `False`. (So why it is a function?)

Comment: Nope, you can't get anything outside the largest possible update region.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz but maybe we can force it to think it has a bigger height, and the `Paint` procedure render that in a separate bitmap ?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I correct it.

Comment: Nope. Think of it as a grid displaying a bunch of records retrieved from a table. The grid does not know anything about other records. Not sure about the analogy but anyway, rendering occurs on a device context, a couple ways acquiring one, none of which cares for invisible offset. To make the box think that it is larger, you have to make it so.

Comment: Even if you extend the size of your scrollbox off the form, off the screen, what you don't see isn't even drawn at all. You can't take a screenshot of something that isn't visible.

Comment: It should be possible to make several BitBlt and scroll the control in between. The bitmaps are then combined to one or you BitBlt in the appropriate area of the target bitmap. I know that SnagIt does it this way.

Comment: Probably you won't find a reference saying that this is not possible because references generally talk about what is possible. But reading it will give you a better idea of what the expect. Start from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/painting-and-drawing) and read it all. It will still take much less time than making futile attempts.

Comment: FSCapture, I used, had a "scroll refresh time" setting involving capturing scrollable content, as @Uwe suggested. That's because you can't be sure how much time will it take for the control have its invalidated region updated. In general, not reliable, I don't suggest the method.

Answer (score 2):

I did it by scrolling the box and making a capture every time. It's not nice to see that flicker on the screen, but at least it works. And it might capture something else if some window appears on the screen at that time...

```
procedure CaptureScrollBox(ABox: TScrollBox; FileName: String);
var vBmp: Graphics.TBitmap;
    vControlDC: HDC;
    Org: TPoint;
    PngImg: TPngImage;
    Y, P: Integer;
begin
 PngImg:= TPngImage.Create;
 vControlDC:= GetWindowDC(ABox.Handle);
 vBmp:= Graphics.TBitmap.Create;
 vBmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
 vBmp.Width  := ABox.ClientWidth;
 vBmp.Height := ABox.VertScrollBar.Range;
 Org.X:= ABox.Left; Org.Y:= ABox.Top;
 Org:= ABox.Parent.ClientToScreen(Org);
 Org.X:= ABox.ClientOrigin.X - Org.X;
 Org.Y:= ABox.ClientOrigin.Y - Org.Y;
 P:= ABox.VertScrollBar.Position;

 Y:= 0;
 repeat
  ABox.VertScrollBar.Position:= Y; ABox.Repaint;
  if ABox.VertScrollBar.Position <> Y then begin
   Org.Y:= Org.Y + ( Y - ABox.VertScrollBar.Position );
   BitBlt(vBmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, Y, vBmp.Width, vBmp.Height, vControlDC, Org.X, Org.Y, SRCCOPY);
   Break;
  end
  else begin
   BitBlt(vBmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, Y, vBmp.Width, vBmp.Height, vControlDC, Org.X, Org.Y, SRCCOPY);
   Inc(Y, ABox.ClientHeight);
  end;
 until False;

 ABox.VertScrollBar.Position:= P;
 PngImg.Assign(vBmp);
 PngImg.SaveToFile(FileName);
 vBmp.Free;
 ReleaseDC(ABox.Handle, vControlDC);
 PngImg.Free;
end;
```

Comment: This is a workaround for your actual problem but does not answer the question whether it is possible or not to *"capture the whole area of the control, like it is expanded that no vertical scroll bar is needed"*. If I understand the question correctly that is.

Comment: If the correct answer to the question following its wording is a simple "no", I actually appreciate the workaround, even if strictly speaking it is not a valid answer. IIRC, a simple "no" is not even a valid answer in terms of minimum characters.